# Calculate new points given an angle

Tags: trigonometry

So I have two points with $(x,y)$ coordinates. This two points draw a line. This line can be rotated $360^{\circ}$  from the center (like a compass).

I need a formula to find calculate the new points coordinates when the line is rotated given the value in degrees.

Sorry if this sounds unclear, I'm not a math person :) Thank you!

Comment: Rotating 360 degrees is equivalent to rotating 0 degrees, so the co-ordinates stay the same.

Comment: what point does the line rotate around? as that effects where the points move to. if it is around (x,y)=(0,0) then it is very easy.

Comment: First of all, you should help people to help you by providing notations : $(x_c,y_c)=((x_1+x_2)/2,(y_1+y_2)/2)$ for the center's coordinates and $\theta$ for the angle. The principle is 1) move the current point $(x,y)$ to $(0,0)$ by **subtracting** $(x_c,y_c)$ to $(x,y)$, 2) perform the rotation by using the $\theta$ rotation matrix transforming point $(x,y)$ into $(x'=x \cos \theta-y \sin \theta,y'=...)$, 3) then move back to the original situation by **adding** $(x_c,y_c)$ to $(x',y')$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is

"If you have two points $p_0=(x_0,y_0)$ and $p_1=(x_1,y_1)$,then they have a point half way along the line between them $p_m=(x_m,y_m)=(\frac{x_0+x_1}{2},\frac{y_0+y_1}{2})$. Now if this line is rotated by some angle $\theta$, around $p_m$ then what are the new coordinates of the rotated points,$p_0'$ and $p_1'$."

Now rotating around an arbitrary point can be a bit messy so lets make it simpler by moving the points so that there mid-point is at the origin, we do this but "subtracting" the mid-point to get two new points $p_{01}=(x_{01},y_{01})=(x_0-x_m,y_0-y_m)$ and $p_{11}=(x_{01},y_{01})=(x_1-x_m,y_1-y_m)$. Shown below, where the red is the original points and the connecting line and blue is the point when they have been shifted so that the mid point is the origin.

[image]

Then rotating around the origin by some angle $\theta$ is described by the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). So when we rotate the points we get two new points $p_{02}=(x_{02},y_{02})=(x_{01}cos(\theta)-y_{01}sin(\theta),y_{01}cos(\theta)+x_{01}sin(\theta)$ and $p_{12}=(x_{02},y_{01})=(x_{11}cos(\theta)-y_{11}sin(\theta),y_{11}cos(\theta)+x_{11}sin(\theta)$. Show below, where blue is the original points and line and green is the rotated points and line.

[image]

Now to move the line back, to do this we "add" back the mid-point to get $p_{03}=(x_{02}+x_m,y_{02}+y_m)$ and $p_{13}=(x_{12}+x_m,y_{12}+y_m)$. Shown below, where green is the rotated points and line and the yellow points and line is the shifted system.

[image]

so if we compare the transformed line and points (yellow) to the the original line and points (red)

[image]

hopefully that helps